# Cannot access server running NordVPN when connecting to my home using Asus router VPN

Tags: networking, server, vpn

I have a custom Asus router which allows me to set up a VPN server to access my home network when i'm out.

I have a home server running on port 192.168.50.50, this home server is running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and is always connected to NordVPN.

Whenever I am at home, I can access an item on my server running NordVPN over my local network no problem. For example, my plex server running on 192.168.50.50:32400.

But as soon as i'm out of the house and connect to my home using the asus VPN and try to load 192.168.50.50:32400, it times out.

If i'm out the house and connect to my home using the asus VPN, and the ubuntu server is **not** connected to nordVPN, I can access it fine.

I have tried multiple things, including whitelisting my entire subnet using

`nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.50.0/24`

But I just cannot connect when NordVPN is running.

What configuration do I need to change to get this working?

Comment: This will be hard to troubleshoot. However, I think this is not about Ubuntu, but all about conflicts between the two VPNs you are running.  Basically when your remote computer sends a request (for a video for example) to your home server, the home server sends the response to the NordVPN server in Timbuktu. So your remote computer does not receive it.

Comment: Maybe my understanding is wrong, but I thought that was the purpose of the NordVPN whitelist feature? I thought when you whitelist a certain port/programme, requests to them are not routed through NordVPN?

Comment: This is my understanding as well. When you remote connect to your home network using the Asus router VPN, what IP address does the Asus VPN assign to your remote computer? If it is not in the range of 192.168.50.0/24 then you have a problem.

Comment: How can I find out what IP the Asus VPN is assigning my computer?

Comment: The command `ip address show` should tell you all the IP addresses your computer has. Look for the address assigned to the interface `tun0` or something similar.

Comment: I cant picture this being an issue? Because if the nordVPN is disabled on the ubuntu server, I can access it fine when going through the Asus VPN on the router? It only becomes unavailable when I enable nordvpn on it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147069/discussion-between-user68186-and-s-r).